# In Java, length of "\1", "\12", "\377", "\378, what are the differences and why?

Tags: java, string

The answers are 1, 1, 1, 2.

Why the length of "\377" is 1? And why the length of "\378" is 2? What is the difference?

Could someone help out? Thanks.

Comment: _"The answers are..."_ but what is the question? Please share some code

Comment: `"\377"` is `"ÿ"`. `"\378"` is `\37` followed by `8`.

Answer (score 1):

Those are [octal escapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7). They are ways to represent Unicode characters, but only in the range of U+0000 to U+00FF.

They exist basically **only** for compatibility with C. I find that reason a bit weak, since most of Java is not compatible to C anyway, but I guess this means you can at least copy more of the string literals from C code to Java code.

`\377` is the highest possible octal escape, representing U+00FF. Thus `"\378"` is interpreted as the octal escape `\37` followed by the plain old character `8`.

In Java the more common and more useful way to escape (arbitrary) Unicode characters are [Unicode Escapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3). They look like `\u0020` (i.e. `\u` followed by exactly 4 hex digits).